# How do I create an installation file for my website?

Tags: php, html, compilation, installation

A friend of mine and I are currently creating a webshop as a school project. We want other students to be able to install our website easily much like WordPress or IPBoard. My question is, is there a script that can create this for you or do we have to compile it ourselves? In that case, what language or method should we utilize to compile the website?

I know the question is broad but I don't know how much detail I should go into but if you have any questions I'll answer them the best I can.

Thank you in advance for responding.

Comment: PHP websites are not 'compiled'. Installation scripts are usually used to setup the database, check folder permission, server requirements, etc. And yes, your question is too broad. Limit it to a specific problem.

Comment: It's indeed a very broad question with many aspects to address. You need to create the database, deploy the files, check the server config, you probably want the students to configure the webshop aswell. There's a lot to think about and no simple answer since it so specific to your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you could look at how one installs other CMS like Wordpress, Drupal, Etc. and get ideas from them. There are hosting providers that provide 1-click installs for wordpress, but not that many (from my understanding) that do the same for Drupal systems.

Also, looking at the way one installs those CMS platforms would help you build a better install setup for your users